# FileNotFoundError when using shutil in python

Tags: python, shutil

Hello i worte the folloring funktion, it shouid move files from one folder to a nother one. This works most off the time but sometimes it throws this exception. Maby every 100 run.

```
def __move(self):
    directory = os.fsencode(self._temp_path)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if ".png" in filename: 
            shutil.move(f"{self._temp_path}/{filename}",f"{self._image.path}.png")
```

This throws a Exception that i dont quite understand it is the followring:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\math-milan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 825, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'temp/image_0.png' -> 'C:\\Users\\math-milan\\Desktop\\src/downloads/#0012c-name_of_image.png'
```

My question is on what the FileNotFoundError is. Dose it not find the source or the destination. The Images get deleted from the src folder so i thing that means the it trys to transfer the images to the dst folder.

Thangs on any advice

Try to move files with shutil in python

Comment: It means that the the call to `os.rename()` failed, because the file `src` didn't exist.

Comment: If you only want to process `.png` files, use `glob.glob(os.path.join(self._temp_path, '*.png"))`

Comment: Why are you moving all the source files to the same destination file?

Comment: Yes this war my thought as well but the problem is as i understand it os.listdir shoud list all path too valid files in the folder

Comment: I don't, but I thought it had nothing to do with the problem, so I left it out.